# New Added Local Administrator cannot access drive and not able to access drive

Tags: permissions, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I've only been with this company for a month as system administrator, the servers was not install by me, a file server - member of a domain

I found some curious setting and errors need to help !!!

**The file server architecture as below :**
[The file server architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuoRS.png)

1. Why is it designed this way, with a Hyper-V running on Windows 2019 and two guest Windows running on Hyper-V?
2. As a domain administrator (also member of local administrators group), when I log in and attempt to access the D:\ drive, I encounter the error "shown in capture 2. I've even created a local administrator account, but the same error persists. Both accounts can perform administrative tasks but can't access D:

Strangely, the built-in Administrator can access D:. Why is this the case?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzQL1.png)

3. The HQ staff informed me that D:\ is mounted by Hyper-V, which is why I can't access it.

Is this true? If so, how can I resolve this issue? (Hyper-V manager is depicted in below capture.)

[Hyper-V Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOaWU.png)

Comment: "From the perspective of the management operating system, these pass-through disks are in an “offline” state, which means that direct read and write access to the physical hard disks is not available." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn803924(v=ws.11)#pass-through-disk-storage

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the design decisions that have been made in your company. There might be a an workload being used which requires direct disk access. You should be able to access the disk from a VM, where its mounted on.

You can also use the `Get-VHD` powershell command, this is to retrieve information about the attached VHDX files, which represent pass-through disks.

Comment: I think that there is some icalcs restrictions applied, we do this for example on backup drives to harden it